# How to pass JSON object from API to server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using `React` and `node.js`, and I've used react's `fetch` to `POST` some Login credentials to my restAPI in order to receive a webtoken...

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
           username: this.state.username_login,
           password: this.state.password_login
        })
     })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson); //this is the object containing the token
    })

    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("request failed");
    })
  }
```

so `responseJson` is the the object containing my web token. The request was successful and now I've passed it to the client. Now, I am thinking of saving it to a `cookie`.

How can I send this to the server? Should I make a `POST` request? If so how do I do that once the JSON object is received? If there is a better way, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are automatically passed along any HTTP request made with `fetch`